# Updating from Database to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` that is populated by a `DefaultTableModel` which again is populated from a method call that reads data from the database. I have  "Create" and "Delete" buttons added to actionlistner, and these do their functions right. But I can't see the changes immediately in the `JTable` after deleting or creating rows. I wan't the `JTable` to update itself right after the buttons have been pressed. As it is now, I have to restart the program to see it. I have tried `tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()` after the button-calls in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, no effect.
 Hope I have explained myself clearly enough, and thanks for helping.

```
else if (e.getSource() == deleteTreatmentBtn)
        {
            treatmentName = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("blabla");
            Treatment treatment = controllerApp.readTreatment(treatmentName);

            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, treatment.toString(),
                    "Blabla?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                controllerApp.deleteTreatment(treatmentName);
                confirmationTime.confirmation("blabla",
                        "blabla");
```

Comment: Have you considered calling `removeRow` and `addRow`?  You should NEVER call any of the `fireTableXxx` methods from outside the context of the model, they are not for you use...

Comment: Yes, but to remove row i need to know what row to remove, and addRow I need all the columns new values and inserting them. Wouldn't a new "refresh"-call to the database, and populating the Jtable from new be easier/the right thing to do ?

Comment: Why?  Didn't you just carry out the operation?  It would be faster to simply remove or add the row directly to the table on successful complication against the database then try and call the database again, which throws away things like sort orders and possible column configurations...

Comment: When I'm deleting, I'm deleting a object, so I'm not sure how to get the rows number filled when using removeRow(?).

Comment: This is a drag of `DefaultTableModel`, personally, I'd create a custom model extending from `AbstractTableModel` and then provide `add` and `remove` methods which accepted the row object itself. This way it's easier to manage, as you are not constantly converting from one to another and you gain the ability to do object based lookups (ie via some kind of `List`)

Comment: added the code for the delete button